How to fetch group calendar events using Azure application-only permissions? Error: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again
Summary:
I'm trying to fetch group calendar and its events using Azure application-only permissions, but I'm getting an error.
Error Message:

Code:
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider); var events = await graphClient .Groups[groupId] .Calendar .Events .Request() .GetAsync();

Ensured the application has the required permissions (Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite,
Group.ReadWrite.All) in the Azure portal.
Verified the client credentials (client ID, tenant ID, client secret) are correct.
Checked that the application is granted admin consent for the required permissions.

Question:
What could be causing the ErrorAccessDenied when trying to fetch the group calendar events with application-only permissions? How can I resolve this issue?
Additional Information:

The application is registered in Azure AD and has been granted admin consent for the necessary permissions.
I'm using the Microsoft Graph SDK for .NET.
The application works correctly for other API calls (e.g., fetching user details).

Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

Application permissions are not supported to list group calendar events, make use of delegated flow and delegated permissions. Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.


Note that: Application permissions are not supported to list group calendar events, make use of delegated flow and delegated permissions. Check this MsDoc

I granted Application permissions to the Microsoft Entra ID application as you:

And when I tried to retrieve the Group calendar events using Client credential flow and got the same error:

Hence you need to switch to delegated flow and grant delegated API permissions to get the group calendar events.
To fetch group calendar events grant Group.Read.All delegated API permission:

And switch to any delegated flow/user interactive flow. Refer this MsDoc
For sample, I made use of Authorization code provider like below:
Generate auth code by using below endpoint and sign-in the browser:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://replyUrlNotSet
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345


I am able to fetch group calendar event successfully by using below code:
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "TenantID";
var clientId = "ClientID";
var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
var groupId = "GroupID";
var authorizationCode = "code";

var options = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, authorizationCode, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authCodeCredential, scopes);
try
{
    var result = await graphClient.Groups[groupId].Calendar.Events.GetAsync();
    if (result != null && result.Value != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calendar Events Retrieved:");
        foreach (var eventItem in result.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Event: {eventItem.Subject}");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No events found.");
    }
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error Code: {odataError.Error.Code}");
    throw;
}


